# How can I catch this exception in iOS?

Tags: ios, exception, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

Here is part of my code:

```
self.rearPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.rearPicker.delegate = self;
self.rearPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.rearPicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.rearPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[self presentViewController:self.rearPicker animated:YES completion:^{
    // send log to my server.And log's success in sending shows that  everything goes pretty well until this line.
    @try {
    // I think it's this line of code that causes crash on some device. What else can I do to avoid crashes besides @try-@catch.
    [self.rearPicker performSelector:@selector(takePicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.f];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    @finally {
         // do nothing for now
    }

   }];
});
```

// According to my log in server and crash log, on some device my App can normally execute

```
[self.rearPicker performSelector:@selector(takePicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.f];
```

// But crashed somewhere after this. There are two kinds of crash log as bellow:

1. *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)
2. *** Camera: Error finding capture device format for mogul

//  I am really confused. How can I catch these two exceptions? Thanks for you patience and kindness!

Comment: please add the takePicture method

Comment: takePicture method it the iOS SDK method "-[UIImagePickerController takePicture]". Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the @try all you're doing is dispatching something to happen later. The @try doesn't contain the thing that happens later, only the request to do it.

Instead, you should dispatch to your own method and then inside that method you add your exception handling directly around the problem call (`takePicture`). Note that if that call does anything asynchronous then you will have a similar problem.

In general it's best to add breakpoints and work out why you have a problem so you can add checks to avoid that situation rather than trying to deal with it after it has happened.

Comment: so what about doing it in this way:    @try {   sleep(3);   [self.rearPicker takePicture]; }  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.